# Spring social + Maven: import can not be resolved

Tags: spring, maven, spring-social, spring-tool-suite

I have a maven + spring + hibernate + spring social project and got into some problems. What I did is the following.

1. I updated STS, which caused a lot of problems.
2. Reinstalled STS
3. Deleted /.m2 folder and downloaded all dependencies again, update, clean and so on.
4. My dependencies seems to work again and I have no errors in my pom.xml, seems like everything is downloaded.

The problem is that the following imports does not work anymore (error message : "the import .... can not be resolved"):

```
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.EnableJdbcConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.config.annotation.EnableFacebook;
import org.springframework.social.linkedin.config.annotation.EnableLinkedIn;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.config.annotation.EnableTwitter;
```

However there is a bunch of other spring social import's that does work like:

```
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ReconnectFilter;
```

My huge pom.xml file. Sorry for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.courseportal</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <name>course_portal</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
        <spring.framework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.version>
        <commons-dbcp.version>1.4</commons-dbcp.version>
        <sl4j.version>1.7.2</sl4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <hsqldb.version>2.2.9</hsqldb.version>
        <org.springframework.social-version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social-version>
        <org.springframework.social.facebook-version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social.facebook-version>
        <org.springframework.social.twitter-version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social.twitter-version>
        <org.springframework.social.linkedin-version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework.social.linkedin-version>     
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.springframework.security-version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security-version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <sourceIncludes>
                        <sourceInclude>**/*.*</sourceInclude>
                    </sourceIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Configuration which allows JUnit tests to be placed in the same folder as java files -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
                    <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- Configuration which allows configuration files (such as xml files) to be placed in the same folder as java files -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- **********************************************************************
               **               Json mapper                                      **
               ********************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codeartisans</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.json</artifactId>
            <version>20130213</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- **********************************************************************
               **               SPRING DEPENDENCIES                              **
               ********************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- **********************************************************************
               **               HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES                           **
               ********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- **********************************************************************
               **               DATABASE DEPENDENCIES                            **
               ********************************************************************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.156</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
             **                    OTHER DEPENDENCIES                            **
             ********************************************************************** -->

        <!-- Mail service -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- **********************************************************************
             **         TEST DEPENDENCIES                                        **
             *********************************************************************** -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- **********************************************************************
             **         New!! used for spring social                             **
             *********************************************************************** -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social.facebook-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social.facebook-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social.twitter-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-linkedin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social.linkedin-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.159</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release-local</url>
            <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

[image: Dependency Hierarchy]

What can cause this and what are the potential solutions to it?

Comment: have you tried to run your maven with -e and -U option? -e is for complete stacktrace and -U is for complete Debug. You will see the error and post the stacktrace of it please.

Comment: Can I do that from STS?

Comment: Just do it from a console. You shouldn't do everything through an IDE. That's simply being lazy, or even: lazier to learn. Doing things from the command-prompt/shell allows you really figure out what's going on. The IDE is a whole other layer on top of that which over-complicates and hides things for you.

Comment: Okey, but what command shall I run? I just installed Maven besides STS so I can try it from the console. But I don't know how to interpret "run your maven" as Jorge said.